# Redwood JS: Cannot query field XX on type "Query"

Tags: graphql, redwoodjs

I'm having a GraphQL issue that popped up recently and I'm not sure where to go since I believe i'm following the GraphQL documentation correctly on querying.

I have the following model.

```
model Contract {
  id           Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  userId       Int?
  vin          String
  make         String
  model        String
  year         Int
  ownersName   String     @default("")
  createdAt    DateTime   @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime   @updatedAt
  ownersEmail  String     @default("")
  User         User?      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  Dealership   Dealership @relation(fields: [dealershipId], references: [id])
  notes        Note[]
  dealershipId Int
}
```

Here are the related types

```
type Contract {
    id: Int!
    vin: String!
    make: String!
    model: String!
    year: Int!
    ownersName: String!
    User: User
    userId: Int
    createdAt: DateTime
    updatedAt: DateTime
    ownersEmail: String
  }
  type Query {
    contractsByUser: [Contract]
  }
```

and here is my query which i'm exporting from a cell

```
export const QUERY = gql`
  query ContractByUser {
    contractsByUser {
      id
      vin
      make
      model
      year
      ownersName
      createdAt
    }
  }
```

I get the following error.

```
api | ERROR [2021-08-04 13:28:03.477 +0000] (apollo-graphql-server): GraphQL didEncounterErrors
api |     errors: [
api |       {
api |         "message": "Cannot query field \"contractsByUser\" on type \"Query\".",
api |         "locations": [
api |           {
api |             "line": 2,
api |             "column": 3
api |           }
api |         ]
api |       }
api |     ]
api | INFO [2021-08-04 13:28:03.479 +0000] (apollo-graphql-server): GraphQL willSendResponse
api |
api | Error: Cannot query field "contractsByUser" on type "Query".
api |
api |
api | POST /graphql 400 21.533 ms - 1329
api |
api | GraphQLError: Cannot query field "contractsByUser" on type "Query".
```

This is definitely a validation error, but I'm not sure what i've missed or done incorrectly. I'm on the latest Version of Redwood and updated the breaking changes. Any help would be good. Maybe its not generating types correctly or.... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: playground docs - is this query there - is it working in playground? if not - bad BE/code/config

Answer (score 0):

I had redwood graphql function misconfigured and it wasn't importing the generated types.

Where I was:

```
import schemas from 'src/graphql/**/*.js'
import { db } from 'src/lib/db'
import { logger } from 'src/lib/logger'
import services from 'src/services/**/*.js'
```

Where I needed to be:

```
import schemas from 'src/graphql/**/*.{js,ts}'
import { db } from 'src/lib/db'
import { logger } from 'src/lib/logger'
import services from 'src/services/**/*.{js,ts}'
```